# XRM setDisable() does not work on browsers other than IE

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, dynamics-crm-2011, xrm

There’s an error on our XRM form when it is opened from a browser other than IE. You can see the unhelpful message on the image link.

[image]

The error is unclear so I debugged it, and it led me to an error on the javascript function on page load.
It couldn’t use the XRM setDisabled() function properly:

```
Xrm.Page.getControl("simpeg_tipelokasi").setDisabled(true);
```

On IE it works and the field is disabled, but strangely it does not work on Chrome and Firefox. Can you help me figure out why it does not work on those browsers? Thanks a lot!

**EDIT:**

My bad, it's actually a problem which lies within the ActiveX configuration of both browsers and **not** on the setDisabled function. I must have missed it when debugging a while ago.
See my new post on this url:
[Alternative to XRM Javascript calling webservice using ActiveX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15632821/alternative-to-xrm-javascript-calling-webservice-using-activex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the roll-up of your organization to at least 12 (the latest at the moment). I'm surprised, though, that you got as far as to actually getting the error. You shouldn't be able to log in and display the "main" forms when using unsupported browser.

EDIT:

It's **definitely** not an issue with RU12 and browser brand. I just created a new organization and added the following functionality via a web resource.

```javascript
function disableFullNameOnLoad(){
  Xrm.Page.getControl("fullname").setDisabled(true);
  alert("Full name disabled on load.");
}

function enableFullNameOnSave(){
  Xrm.Page.getControl("fullname").setDisabled(false);
  alert("Full name enabled on save.");
}
```

As the nomenclature implies, the disabling is performed in the form's *onload* and enabling in its *onsave*. I entered the CRM (RU12, OP) using FF, IE and Cr. The behavior was consistent - greyed-out *fullname* as I open the form and *editable* when I save it.

So whatever issue there's on your platform, it's not directly related to cross browser incompatibility. Can you check again that you get the discrepancy in behavior between IE and FF when you add the exact code from my examples, connected to the events exactly the way I described, please.

Comment: It actually worked and on some forms it would run well, but on this  one there was this problem. I get that even the application wouldn't load if the rollup has not been applied yet, so I guess the problem lies within my code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have rechecked my code and it turns out the problem wasn't actually because of the setDisabled (my bad, sorry!).

It was actually because of ActiveX of the form when calling a webservice because on chrome/Firefox can't create a new ActiveX instance. I'll edit/post a new question regarding this error. Sorry for misleading question, but thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Try using XrmServiceToolKit new version which should support cross browser compatibility:

http://xrmservicetoolkit.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks, I will look it up. It seems to be one of the best option for XRM customization at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not currently on Rollup 12 then Chrome is not supported officially.

If you can, then I would try and upgrade to get the new cross browser support offered via [Rollup 12](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=36229). Make sure you check out the [code validation tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30151) to make sure your code and customizations don't have any issues.

If this isn't an option then you can try the [xrmservicetoolkit](http://xrmservicetoolkit.codeplex.com/) which is a CRM JavaScript library.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion on code validation tool and the javascript library. Our development was halted before the Rollup 12 was released, but then continued after it was released, and as expected we found several issues, one of those was this one. It was quite unfortunate that most of the toolkits were released just recently, and we had to cope with custom-made libraries.